# capital letters in firt letter

Tags: capitalization, letters

In python, I want a program that turn the first leter on a word capital letter.

For exemple:

turn "a red apple is sweeter than a green apple" in "A Red Apple is Sweeter Than A Green Apple"

How can I do?

I've tried this:

```
d = input('insert a quote')
def mydic(d):
  dic = {}
  for i in d:
    palavras = dic.keys()
    if i in palavras:
      dic[i] += 1
    else :
      dic[i] = 1
return dic
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Post/paste what you have so far so we can help you with where you are.

Comment: d = input('insert a quote ')
def mydic (d):
  dic = {}
  for i in d:
      palavras = dic.keys()
      if i in palavras:
          dic[i] +=1 
      else :
          dic[i] = 1
      
  return dic

Comment: Update your question with the code please! :)

Comment: :) done. sorry, I am new here, and I cant past the code very well

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `title()` method.

For example:

```
sentence = str(input("Insert a quote: ")).title()
print(sentence)
```

Input: `a red apple is sweeter than a green apple`

Output: `A Red Apple Is Sweeter Than A Green Apple`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is this:

1. split the input string into words ie. `string.split(' ')` splits a given string by spaces, returns a list.
2. for each word, capitalize the first letter and concatenate onto a bigger string ie. `word[:1].upper() + word[1:]` this will uppercase the first letter
3. Add all the words back into a list and return it.